# Writing strings into CSV in a single row

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am currently having an issue with writing string into a CSV file in a row.

What happen now is, the string is being written into the CSV file word by word in a new row each time.

Instead of writing "This is my string" as a whole, I am getting:
"T
h
i
s..."
as an output.

Here is my code:

```
            v_name = str(input("Please enter name: ")).upper()
            v_contact = str(input("Please enter contact number: "))
            v_company = str(input("Please enter company name: ")).upper()
            v_uen = str(input("Please enter company UEN: ")).upper()
            v_address = str(input("Please enter address: ")).upper()
            full_contact = ("{0} {1} {2}, {3} {4} {5}".format(v_name, id, v_contact, v_company, v_uen, v_address))
            with open ('{0}.csv'.format(today), 'a') as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerows(full_contact)
```

Should I be using concatenate instead? (But I will not have any spacing between all the variables)

And is it possible to write each variable into a different column but in the same row?

Comment: Unrelated: the point of csv is to use a special separator between values. To make sure you find the correct boundaries of your columns later. What would happen with your code when the company name contains a space? Regarding your problem, I guess you shouldn't be using writerows(). Start by learning how to just read/write normal text into files.

Comment: Thanks for the advise.

I have no issue with reading and writing a preloaded dataframe (row by row) into my CSV. It is only when I try to enter the above mentioned inputs into the same CSV where I get the problem.

But I did managed to solve my problem:
`full_contact = ("{0}; {1}; {2}; {3}; {4}; {5}".format(v_name, id, v_contact, v_company, v_uen, v_address))

with open ('{0}.csv'.format(today), 'a') as f:
     f.write(','.join(full_contact.split(';')))`

Comment: Note: you are using write() now ...

Comment: And still: learn how how proper CSV looks like. Your code will fail when values contain an ";" ... so proper csv is also about using quotes, like `"value a"; 5; "value b"; "valuec"`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am still very new to this, but I wish to tackle a problem I am facing at work. Hence the rubbish codes I am writing. =)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding my issue, the following snippet is the solution I found:

```
full_contact = ("{0}; {1}; {2}; {3}; {4}; {5}".format(v_name, idt, v_contact, v_company, v_uen, v_address))

print(full_contact)

with open ('{0}.csv'.format(today), 'a') as f:
     f.write(','.join(full_contact.split(';')))
```